# What time does the firebase.database.ServerValue.timestamp returns?

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to android programming and Firebase. In my project, I am using firebase to save the user last active time by `firebase.database.servervalue.timestamp` directly to firebase database using a handler.

When I am displaying both this `servervalue.timestamp` from this firebase node and `system.currentTimeMillis()` using Toast, both are returning the same date and time.

In this part, I am confused because both values should not be same. Does `serverValue.timestamp` save device to date and time (long) in firebase database??? please help me in this context.

Comment: Firebase uses a UNIX timestamp, so if you're asking if there should be a timezone difference or something, the answer is no. It just uses the time since the Unix epoch.

Comment: Brandon Miller thanks for your answer. I wanted to know the internal mechanism of TimeStamp (UNIX epoch) of firebase. In spite of 11.00 hrs timezone difference, firebase is dealing with my country's standard time without manual insertion of time. Its really amazing. How does it happen??

Answer (score 0):

As you can check in the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue)

```
servervalue.timestamp
```

basicly is a dummy value that tells the server to insert its current timestamp. So it does not depend on your device time